# Angular Datatable page change and search event detection

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular [datatable](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/), I want to detect page change and search event in controller, as I can detect it if I bind it in datatable id, but I want to detect it using angularjs scope

```
$scope.$on('page.dt', function () { 
   // Do something on page change
});

$scope.$on('search.dt', function () {   
   // Do something on search
});
```

Any suggestion for this.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? It could be useful if you indicate your solution if you found it

Comment: @Sagar have you got any solution for this because I am also facing this

Answer (score 4):

I figured this out. Once your dtInstance is defined run this code...

```
        vm.dtInstance.DataTable.on('page.dt', function () {
            //do stuff
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the `$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch('page.dt', function (newVal, oldVal) { 
   if (newVal !== oldVal) {
      // Do something
   }
});
```

Comment: This only seems to get fired when the table is initially rendered, not when a page is actually changed.